# React native navigation with modal: resize; appear from bottom

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

1. How to specifiy modal height react native navigation? It default stretches full screen, how to stretch it half screen?
2. Can the drawer be shown from the bottom?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried and describe how it doesnt work for you.

Comment: you could add some examples?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking for [Modal](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html) in react native, you can proceed below.

1 - To reduce the modal height, you can specify the height inside the most parent *View* element

```
<View style={{height: 60%}}>
```

Also you can import *Dimensions* and use it to get screen's height and width as below,

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const window = Dimensions.get('window');
const screenHeight = window.height;
const screenWidth = window.width;
```

and then you can use this screenHeight and screenHeight into your css.

```
<View style={{height: screenHeight - 80}}> // Any values
```

2 -  Anything's possible and yes we can do that in react native too. But first they are called as ActionSheets(as in iOS) / BottomSheets(as in android). You can check these libraries for android and ios or both.

https://github.com/beefe/react-native-actionsheet  (Both)

https://github.com/cesardeazevedo/react-native-bottom-sheet-behavior (Android)

https://github.com/eyaleizenberg/react-native-custom-action-sheet (iOS)